# SQL*Plus how to accept text variable from prompt?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Im very beginner in psql and i have a question.

Here is the code:

```
SET serveroutput ON
ACCEPT myVariable PROMPT "Input value: ";

BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('My input variable is: '||&myVariable);
 END;
```

Question is very simple: How can i pass text to my variable? If i input a number it is works correctly and i can read in the log my number, but if i pass a text like "mytext" instead of a number, i got an error:

```
    old:BEGIN


     dbms_output.put_line('My input variable is: '||&myVariable);
     END;


    new:BEGIN

  dbms_output.put_line('My input variable is: '||mytext);
 END;

    Error starting at line 5 in command:
    BEGIN
      dbms_output.put_line('My input variable is: '||&myVariable);
     END;
    Error report:
    ORA-06550: 2 sor, 50 oszlop:
    PLS-00201: identifier 'MYTEXT' must be declared
    ORA-06550: 2 sor, 3 oszlop:
    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
    06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
    *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
    *Action:
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to specify the data type as part of the [ACCEPT statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12005.htm). If none is given, it assumes a number.

Try `ACCEPT myVariable CHAR PROMPT 'Input value: ';` instead.

Answer (score 7):

You have to enclose the character substitution variable in quotes when you use it, if it's a string, otherwise Oracle tries to interpret the *value* as an object name. You can see that on the 'new' version (shown because you have `set verify on`), and sexta13 alluded to that too. So you would do:

```
 dbms_output.put_line('My input variable is: '||'&myVariable');
```

But you don't need to concatenate the value in this case (whether it's a number or s string):

```
 dbms_output.put_line('My input variable is: &myVariable');
```

Comment: You should probably use two ampersands:  `dbms_output.put_line('&&myVariable');`  That way it won't ask for the value if it is already defined.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have MYTEXT variable declared anywhere.

```
dbms_output.put_line('My input variable is: '||mytext); -- here is the error. It should be &myVariable.
```

Comment: No, the code is above, the input VALUE is "mytext" that i given!