# can we use more than one function inside one PL/SQL Block

Tags: database, oracle, function, plsql

```
DECLARE
     avg_sal number(8,2);
     c number(8);
     total number(8,2);
     at number(8);
     a number(8);
     rt number(8);
     r number(8);
     y number(8);
     yr number(8);
     c number(8);
     ch number(8);
     FUNCTION cmd_int(amt number,rate number,intrest number)
     RETURN number
     IS
     cint number(8,2);
     BEGIN
     END;

     FUNCTION smp_int(amt number,rate number,intrest number)
     RETURN number
     IS
     sint number(8,2);
     BEGIN
         sint:=(amt*rate*intrest)/100;
         return total/c;
     END;
BEGIN
     dbms_output.put_line('Enter amount :'||:a);
     at:=:a;
     dbms_output.put_line('Enter rate :'||:r);
     rt:=r;
     dbms_output.put_line('Enter year :'||:y);
     yr:=y;
     dbms_output.put_line('1 Compound Intrest');
     dbms_output.put_line('2 Simple Intrest');
     dbms_output.put_line('Enter your choice :'||:c);
     ch:=c;
     CASE 
     WHEN ch:=1 THEN 
        ci:=cmd_int(at,rt,yr);
        dbms_output.put_line('Compound Intrest :'||ci);
     WHEN ch:=2 THEN
        si:=smp_int(at,rt,yr);
        dbms_output.put_line('Simple Intrest :'||si);
END;
```

The above is the code which I want to execute there are two functions cmd_int and smp_int so can I able to execute more than one function inside one PL/SQL Block? Thank you!

Basically i want to execute 1st part when my choice is 1 and second part when my choice is 2.

Comment: Yes - why do you think you can't? You do have a mostake but it's nothing to do with having or calling two functions. How about showing us the error you get?

Comment: @AlexPoole sure! ORA-06550: line 5, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AT" when expecting one of the following: this is the error.

Comment: I've addressed that in my answer now too. Why do you think that error is anything to do with the functions? Also PL/SQL isn't designed to be interactive, and your prompting for bind variables isn't likely to work well even in SQL Developer - you'll be asked for the values before seeing the dbms_output 'prompts' . The client should supply the values to the block.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes you are true error has nothing to do with function but can you able to solve the error? because i am not able to understand error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can define and call as many functions and procedures as you like (and subblocks - up to [a limit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/limits.htm) anyway). The functionality of PL/SQL would be rather curtailed if you couldn't.

But the rest of the code has to be valid. You're [missing an `end case`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/case_statement.htm#CJAGCJFJ):

```
      ...
     CASE 
     WHEN ch:=1 THEN 
        ci:=cmd_int(at,rt,yr);
        dbms_output.put_line('Compound Intrest :'||ci);
     WHEN ch:=2 THEN
        si:=smp_int(at,rt,yr);
        dbms_output.put_line('Simple Intrest :'||si);
     END CASE;
END;
```

And `AT` is [a reserved word in PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/reservewords.htm#CIHDHDCH) so you cannot have a variable with that name, you will need to change it.

You also seem to be confusing PL/SQL local variables (e.g. `r`) with bind variables (`:r`), and you're trying to have interaction between the block and the user, which PL/SQL is not designed for. Once the PL/SQL block is valid your client will either complain that not all variables are bound, or will prompt for them all *before* executing the block, and you will only see the 'prompt' strings from `dbms_output` *after* the block has executed.

Your application or client needs to gather all the values outside the PL/SQL block; Michael Schaefers has shown a common method for SQL Developer or SQL*Plus. You can still combine that with a PL/SQL block if that is part of your assignment.

Comment: ORA-06550: line 5, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AT" when expecting one of the following:

this is the error i got after making changes

Answer (score 2):

To technically answer the question of the headline: yes, you can use more than one function inside a PL/SQL block, as the following example code shows:

```
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE
     FUNCTION cmd_int(amt number,rate number,intrest number)
     RETURN number
     IS
     cint number(8,2);
     BEGIN
      return 4;
     END;

     FUNCTION smp_int(amt number,rate number,intrest number)
     RETURN number
     IS
     sint number(8,2);
     BEGIN
         return 5;
     END;
BEGIN
     dbms_output.put_line('Result 1: ' || cmd_int(1,2,3));
     dbms_output.put_line('Result 2: ' || smp_int(1,2,3));
END;
/
```

Executing this block yields to

```
Result 1: 4
Result 2: 5
```

Now to your problem:

I suggest you create two separate functions `cmd_int` and `smp_int` via `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...` that do, what you want. Since these two are used in the same logical context you can also create a package `CREATE PACKAGE INTEREST` and define both functions within this package.

Then, to ask for user input and to actally use the functions I suggest you stick to an sqlplus script using the `ACCEPT` command or to handle everything in your client application (should you have one).

See Oracle Documenation on [CREATE FUNCTION](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_function.htm#LNPLS01370), [CREATE PACKAGE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_package.htm#LNPLS01371) and [sqlplus ACCEPT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12005.htm)

The basic Idea of an sqlplus script would be

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

ACCEPT a NUMBER PROMPT 'Enter amount: ';
ACCEPT r NUMBER PROMPT 'Enter rate: ';
ACCEPT y NUMBER PROMPT 'Enter year: ';
ACCEPT c NUMBER PROMPT '1 Compount Interest, 2 Simple Interest: ';

SELECT CASE WHEN &&c = 1 THEN cmd_int(a,r,y) ELSE smp_int(a,r,y) END AS Interest FROM DUAL;
```

More infos about using sqlplus can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674252/sqlplus-how-to-accept-text-variable-from-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can define more functions and procedures within a pl/sql block.