# How to pass variable with sys_date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, plsql, parameter-passing

I want to pass sysdate into V_TODAY variable which i can use it for other anounymous block or during spooling. I am writing below code which is giving an error has V_TODAY must be declare. For variable with value NAME and ID i am able to pass the value.

```
SET ECHO OFF;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET HEAD OFF;
SET LIN 256;
SET TRIMSPOOL ON;
SET WRAP OFF;
SET PAGES 100;
SET TERM OFF;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

SPOOL F:\LATEST\Loop_TRE.sql;

PROMPT VAR NAME VARCHAR2(100);
PROMPT VAR ID VARCHAR2(100);
PROMPT VAR V_TODAY date;

BEGIN  
FOR TARGET_POINTER IN (SELECT NAME, ID from D_URL)
    LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DEFINE TARGET = '''||TARGET_POINTER.NAME||''';');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EXEC :NAME  := '''||TARGET_POINTER.NAME||'''; ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DEFINE TARGET1 = '''||TARGET_POINTER.ID||''';');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EXEC :ID  := '''||TARGET_POINTER.ID||'''; ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('@@TGT_DOP.sql;');
  END LOOP;
  Select SYS_DATE INTO V_TODAY from DUAL;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DEFINE V_TODAY = '''||V_TODAY||''';');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EXEC :V_TODAY  := '''||V_TODAY||'''; ');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('@@Loop_TST.sql;');
END;
/

SPOOL OFF;

@@Loop_TRE.sql;
```

Comment: Did you try declaring `V_TODAY` in your anonymous block instead of prompting?

Comment: no i am not declaring just prompting. i can use variable value for name and id in TGT_DOP.sql

Comment: You have sys_date not sysdste, and tend to agree vtoday should be a variable for the into to work,  and you have no where clause

Comment: Not related to your question but your where clause is not ending properly?

Comment: @KaushikNayak i have corrected that its copy paste issue

Comment: Use the `accept variable prompt  ""`  syntax and use &variable inside the block

Comment: can you please may be give an example for the same ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL\*Plus how to accept text variable from prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674252/sqlplus-how-to-accept-text-variable-from-prompt)

Answer (score 1):

Declare V_TODAY in Declare block and use `SYSDATE` instead of SYS_DATE

in Reference with your code:

```
SET ECHO OFF;

.
.
PROMPT VAR NAME VARCHAR2(100);
PROMPT VAR ID VARCHAR2(100);

DECLARE
V_TODAY DATE;
BEGIN
....
...
END LOOP;
Select SYSDATE INTO V_TODAY from DUAL;

...
...
```

Comment: i cannot  use declare here because i am using spooling and it will throw error. As you can see i cann pass the variable for Name and ID without any issue and use it in TGT_DOP.sql. So not understanding why i cannot V_TODAY variable. I have also changed from SYS_DATE to SYSDATE still the same error

Comment: @Andrew : Name and Id you are able to use as these are the attributes of TARGET_POINTER by default. These aren't from the declaration.