# How to Dynamically Format Column Headers with Substitution Variables

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a table that has products defined by an identifying code that begins with a number and ends with a letter such as `1A`, `3B`, `7C`, etc. The query assembles the data I need about these with a `PIVOT` statement. Unfortunately, in Oracle we are not allowed to begin aliases with a number. So far, I have successfully made the query work around that by outputting data that is essentially the following:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
PIVOT ( COUNT(Product) FOR ProductName IN (&product_statement) )
```

where the substitution variable `product_statement` was dynamically generated with the assistance of the same process described here: [How do I set LINESIZE and PAGESIZE with a substitution variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353806/how-do-i-set-linesize-and-pagesize-with-a-substitution-variable). This is a representative result:

```
NAME     | A1 | B3 | C7
Product A| 1  | 2  | 1   
Product B| 3  | 1  | 2
```

Now I am trying to turn those product headings back around. Again with the substitution variable process, I created another variable named `&column_statement` that looks like this (each line is separated by `CHR(10)`):

```
COLUMN A1 TEMP FORMAT A3 HEADING ‘1A’
COLUMN B3 TEMP FORMAT A3 HEADING ‘3B’
COLUMN C7 TEMP FORMAT A3 HEADING ‘7C’
```

My thought process was that I could do the following in SQL*Plus:

```
&column_statement

SELECT * FROM MyTable
PIVOT ( COUNT(Product) FOR ProductName IN (&product_statement) )
/
```

but it gives me the following:

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning “&column_st…” – rest of line ignored.

NAME     | A1 | B3 | C7
Product A| 1  | 2  | 1   
Product B| 3  | 1  | 2
```

What do I have to do to dynamically set the column headers?

Comment: SQL\*Plus cannot recursively expand variables into SQL\*Plus commands and execute them. You would need to execute a valid command, even if it contained variables and you called it dynamically.

Comment: How would I make it do that?

Comment: You would have to `spool` the commands to a temporary script file and execute that, maybe using `set termout off feedback off heading off` etc to suppress unwanted output. It gets messy.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll try that when I am back in the office on Monday and let you know how it goes. Unfortunately, the whole thing is a bit messy, that's why I'm trying to make a script to handle this once instead of hard coding it over and over as things change.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, I took your advice and found a way to make it work. I detailed it in my answer below. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out based on William Robertson's suggestion. I spooled the data into an SQL file, then ran that file I just created within the script. It flows like this:

```
SET HEADING OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SPOOL /file_location/column_headers.sql

-- SELECT statement to dynamically make the column header string. Example output:
-- COLUMN A1 TEMP FORMAT A3 HEADING ‘1A’
-- COLUMN B3 TEMP FORMAT A3 HEADING ‘3B’
-- COLUMN C7 TEMP FORMAT A3 HEADING ‘7C’

SPOOL OFF

SET HEADING ON
SET PAGESIZE 100
SET TERMOUT ON

@/file_location/column_headers.sql

-- Now run the other query that uses these headers
SELECT …
```

I wouldn't call it the most elegant solution, but it definitely did the trick and has reduced a lot of hard coded queries.